# Fantasy Novel - Female Protagonist who climbs a tower and encounters magical obstacles before facing off with a wizard

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember the title of a fantasy novel I read years ago.  I remember reading it in paperback format in the early to mid 90's, so I'm guessing it was written in the 80's or 90's.  The protagonist was a female.  I believe she had red hair and lived in a castle.  I know the climactic scene involved her climbing a tower and facing various magical obstacles before facing off with some kind of wizard type character.  I also want to say that fire played some integral part, but I can't remember for sure.  Anyone know this book?

Comment: Uhm...I was about to suggest that the description is applicable to too many possible books, but a thought occurs: did the magic system revolve around knot-work?

Comment: - 1, this is far to general to be anything but a guessing game

Answer (score 20):

Did she kill dragons before facing off with the wizard? If so, could it be *The Hero and the Crown*, by Robin McKinley? It was published in 1984 and features a red-haired heroine who develops a protection against fire that allows her to kill dragons. Near the end of the book she climbs a magical tower to fight a wizard. There's a summary of the story [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hero_and_the_Crown).

Answer (score 10):

This makes me think of the Darkover series by Marion Zimmer Bradley. I just Googled it and one of the novels in the series is called 'Stormqueen!: A Darkover Novel'. The cover has a redhead atop a tower with lightning all around. There was lots of magic in that series, strong female characters, issues about using magical powers, hiding magical powers, escaping from towers, etc. I read the series in the 80's.
[image]

Comment: Darkover has psi powers, but not magic.  No wizards.  And Dorilys, pictured on the cover you included, did not climb the tower; she lived in that castle.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "Bronwyn’s Bane" by Elizabeth Ann Scarborough? It was published in 1984. The cover shows a red-headed female warrior fighting some kind of serpent with a castle in the background. I did read it, but it was many years ago and I don't remember all the details.

Comment: A notable thing about "Bronwyn's Bane" was that she was cursed at a young age and unable to tell the truth.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but was it a series? A quartet perhaps? Possibly [The Song of the Lioness Quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Song_of_the_Lioness) by Tamora Pierce? I'm not sure when it was written, but the first book in the quartet ([Alanna - the First Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanna%3a_The_First_Adventure)) definitely